# Analytical solution to $x_n=x_{n-1}^2\cdot K$

Tags: convergence-divergence, z-transform

I have a problem where I am able to find to solution using an iterative process.
The problem (simplified) goes as follow:

$$ x_n=x_{n-1}^2\cdot K $$

Where $ K<1 $. Actually $ K \approx0.01685$

I know the value of $x_0$ ($x_0=3.089$), so using a software like excel or matlab I can iterate that problem and I see that the value converge quite quickly towards 0. The information I want is the sum of the elements, which I believe, should converge to a constant value since each elements converges towards 0.

$$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x_n$$

I would like try solving the problem using an analytical approach to find the limit of the convergence as a function of $x_0$ and $K$.

I tried to solve this using the Z-Transform. But have some troubles.

First, I am not sure if I should write : $X=X^2\cdot Z^{-1}\cdot K$ or  $X=(X\cdot Z^{-1})^2\cdot K$

The second solution doesn't seems right as it doubles the delay, but I feel like a skipped a step if I use the first version.

If I use the first version of the equation. I then substitute $Z=e^{sT}$ where I set $T=1$

I then have 
$$ X=X^2\cdot Z^{-1}\cdot K$$ 
$$ X = X^2\cdot e^{-s}\cdot K $$
$$ X = \frac{1}{Ke^{-s}}$$

And from there, I am not sure how to handle the rest. If I can make the inverse Laplace, I hope to get a function of a variable that represent the iteration and that will surely converge to the value I am looking for.

Any idea? I am not sure if I used a correct approach or not.
Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Isn't it $x_n$ on the left side? not clear to me why you need z-transform.

Comment: If $x_n=x_{n-1}^2 \cdot K$, then use induction to show $x_n=x_0^{2^n} \cdot K^{2^n-1}$.

Comment: Hint: if $x_n>0$ then $\ln x_n=2\ln x_{n-1}+\ln k$. Or with $a_n=\ln x_n$ we have $a_n=2a_{n-1}+\ln k$. Even better, $(a_n+\ln k)=2(a_{n-1}+\ln k)$.

Comment: Or $x_nK = x_{n-1}^2K^2$. Put $y_n = x_nK$ so $y_n = y_{n-1}^2$. Then $\log y_n = 2\log y_{n-1}$. Put $z_n = \log y_n$ and then $z_n = 2z_{n-1}$ so $z_n = 2^nz_0$....

Comment: The resulting series $$ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x_n = \frac{1}{K} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (Kx_0)^{2^n} $$ is an example of [*lacunary functions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lacunary_function). I would be surprised if reduces to a nice closed form, considering that its behavior near singularities seems so erratic compared to elementary functions.

Answer (score 0):

By a change of variable $y=Kx$, you can temporarily ignore $K$, as

$$y_n=y_{n-1}^2.$$

Then by induction, the general term of the series is

$$y_n=y_0^{2^n}$$

and AFAIK, there is no closed form for

$$\sum_{k=0}^n y_0^{2^k}.$$

For small $y_0$ (yours is about $0.052$), the approximation

$$y_0+y_0^2+y_0^4+y_0^8$$ is excellent.